# Celerybeat does not start in detach mode

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have django 1.11.4 app and use celery 4.1.0 for background periodic tasks. Celery was daemonized according to documentation and was working fine until... I don't know what happened, basically. It suddenly got broken.

When I execute `/etc/init.d/celerybeat` start it writes following exception to `/var/log/celery/beat.log` and halts:

```
[2017-09-04 18:33:38,485: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2017-09-04 18:33:38,485: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2017-09-04 18:33:38,486: CRITICAL/MainProcess] beat raised exception <class 'django.db.utils.InterfaceError'>: InterfaceError
("(0, '')",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hikesadmin/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'scheduler'
```

Here is the **full log**: https://pastebin.com/92iraMCL

I've remove all my tasks and retained simple **celery.py** tasks file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
import django

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

django.setup()

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('myapp')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task
def gogo():
    print("GOGO")

print(123123123)
```

But celerybeat still does not work. It **prints "123123123"** and after that halts with same exception.

I've researched deeper and figured out that the problem is in the `--detach` modifier. When I launch it without it, it works:

```
/usr/local/bin/celery beat --app=hike_engine -S django -f /var/log/celery/beat.g -l INFO --workdir=/home/hikesadmin/engine --pidfile=/var/run/celery/beat.pid
```

When I add `--detach`, celery goes broken.

**Please help me to trace and fix the problem. Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can start a detached beat instance via --detach IIRC. We are using supervisor to start/stop/restart our beat instance:

Add /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery-beat.conf

```
[program:celery-beat]
command=/path/to/env/bin/celery beat -A your.settings.module --loglevel=INFO --workdir /path/to/your/django/project --pidfile=/var/tmp/celery-beat.pid
directory=/path/to/your/django/project

killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true

user=YOURUSERID
group=YOURUSERGROUP

numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/beat.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true

startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600

priority=998
```

then update the configuration
    supervisorctl reread

and finally start the supervised celery beat instance
    supervisorctl start celery-beat

init.d is also documented in the celery docs:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#init-script-celerybeat

Comment: I was using the init.d script as you have mentioned in the end of your reply. And exactly this script got broken for me. Basically it launches celerybeat in --detach mode.

I will try supervisor (thanks for workaround suggestion) but I was fine with init.d script and wonder why it got broken :(